# Mysql Divisão por ZERO, SQL_MODE = 'TRADITIONAL'?

Tags: mysql

Estou com o `SQL_MODE` do `MySQL` como ***TRADICIONAL*** na versão é `5.7.18` e segundo a documentação esse modo faria o `MySQL` funcionar de modo igual os outros bancos como por exemplo `SQL Server`.

Porem quando faço:

```
select 651/0;
```

ao invés de acusar o erro de divisão por zero (`Divide by zero error encountered.`) ele da o resultado como nulo.

Alguém sabe como resolver?

**Documentação:**

***TRADITIONAL***

> Make MySQL behave like a “traditional” SQL database system. A simple description of this mode is “give an error instead of a warning” when inserting an incorrect value into a column. It is one of the special combination modes listed at the end of this section.
>
> **Note**
> The INSERT or UPDATE aborts as soon as the error is noticed. This may not be what you want if you are using a nontransactional storage engine, because data changes made prior to the error may not be rolled back, resulting in a “partially done” update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Segundo a documentação que pode ser acessada [neste link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_error_for_division_by_zero), a divisão por zero não retorna erro para um comando `SELECT`.

> For `SELECT`, division by zero returns `NULL`. Enabling `ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO` causes a warning to be produced as well, regardless of whether strict mode is enabled.

Em operações do tipo `INSERT` e `UPDATE` funcionam normalmente. 
Nesta mesma documentação é citado que o modo `ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO` está depreciado e será removido como um nome de módulo separado.

Comment: Creio que o que a autor da pergunta deseja é que seja reportado um erro e não tratar o NULL indevidamente retornado.

Comment: Obrigado por sinalizar a inconsistência. Realizei o ajuste para que se adeque melhor a questão levantada.